# How do I update my React context after Axios response

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, consumer

### Brief explanation

So What I want to achieve is the following: after confirmation that the user e-mail address and password are correct, a login state must update from false to true. That loginstate however is set up in my App.js and the login confirmation in my Login.js.

### Code

In my App.js, I have the following code:

```
<UserProvider value={{
    loggedIn: this.state.loggedIn,
    actions: {
        logIn: event => {
            this.setState({ loggedIn: true }) 
        }
    }
}}>
    <Route path='/' component={Login} />
</UserProvider>
```

In my Login.js, I have a arrowfunction set up after the user clicks on the login button.

```
requestAuth = () => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH,
            data: {
                username: 'test',
                password: 'test'
            }
        })
        .then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({
                    feedback: "Alright, welcome back! I'm gonna log you in!"
                })
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
                this.setState({
                    feedback: "Sorry, I think your e-mail or password is incorrect. Wanna try again?"
                })
            }
        );

    }
render () {
    return (
        <UserConsumer>
            {({ actions }) => {
                return(
                    <div onClick={this.requestAuth}>
                    </div>
                )
            }}
        </UserConsumer>
    )
}
```

### Question

However, I fail to understand how to update my 'actions.Login' eventset up in the App.js after my login request is succesful.

Comment: It's unclear what problem you have with updating loggedIn. And setLoginstate which is likely responsible for that is not shown.

Comment: I updated my Login.js code. I've set up a div example with an onlick. The problem I'm having is: That onclick launches the requestauth arrow function. Now I'm wondering, after axios returns a succesful resposne, how do I launch my actions.LogIn event (the one defined in my userprovider in app.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAuth` needs access to the `logIn` method: `onClick={() => this.requestAuth(actions)}`

And then `requestAuth` itself can look like this:

```
requestAuth = (actions) => {
    axios(/* ... */)
    .then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response)
            actions.logIn() // there you go
            this.setState({
                feedback: "Alright, welcome back! I'm gonna log you in!"
            })
        }
    )
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it for me

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved with [`context` and `contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype), though it can be considered a quick-and-dirty fix; they were primarily introduced to update legacy code that relies on old `context`. The problem with this approach is that a component is limited to single context at once.

The solution is to connect a component to a context with a HOC that works similarly to Redux `connect`:

```
withUserConsumer = Comp => props => (
  <UserConsumer>
    {user => <Comp user={user} ...props />}
  </UserConsumer>;
);

const LoginWithUser = withUserConsumer(Login);
```

Then `LoginWithUser` gets `user` object as a prop, which can be used in component methods like `requestAuth`.

Comment: This is certaintly also a good solution! However, in this case I followed the answer of @xehpuk where I could easily pass my actions to my loginAuth.